# To get column names from table having a particular value

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

Please tell me How to get column names where column value =123 for a particular row.Thanks in advance .

Comment: That's an unusual thing to want to do, and not particularly easy to do in pure SQL.. Maybe if you give more details on your problem, someone can suggest a better way.

Comment: If you're using another programming language to connect to SQL, it's probably easier to just load the whole row from SQL, then check each column in your application.

Comment: For a particular row i have requestID as a unique id and column names are the roles of an associates. Can i get all the roles for a particular associate say having id=1916 where 1916 will be the column value and role will be the column name.

Comment: are you able to change the database design? It sounds like the roles should be data rather than column names. If not, which programming language are you using? Or is this in pure SQL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
-- Test table
declare @T table(ID int, Col1 varchar(10), Col2 int, Col3 bit, Col4 varchar(max))
insert into @T values (1, '123', 123, 1, 'Some text long text')

-- ID to get one row
declare @ID int
set @ID = 1

-- Value to search for
declare @Val varchar(10) 
set @Val = '123'

select 
  Col.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') as ColName
from (select *
      from @T
      where ID = @ID
      for xml path(''), type) as T(XMLCol)
  cross apply 
    T.XMLCol.nodes('*') as n(Col) 
where Col.value('.', 'varchar(10)') = @Val
```

Result

```
ColName
--------
Col1
Col2
```