# Get column name dynamically by Specific row value

Tags: mysql, database

I am struck at writing a query.
Here I want to show the column name based on some specific value

For Instance, my table is like this:

```
id  | fruits   |vegetables    |softdrink
-----------------------
1   | apple    | Onion        | Pepsi
2   | mango    | Potato       | Coke    
3   | banana   | Bringal      | RedBull
```

If I have a value "mango", then I should get the column name as fruit or

If I have a value "RedBull", then I should get the column name as softdrink

**NOTE**: I have many columns around 48 to get the name from any one of them

Comment: *dynamic sql*, i guess.

Comment: @JW웃 , how can i write dynamic sql

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676354/sql-selecting-columns-based-on-column-value-from-another-table

Comment: @Luceos i have on one table

Comment: if both `e` and `g` in `record` then what should return??@zan

Comment: @DevalShah if e or g is in record then i should get col2 and col1 respectively

Comment: @zan `if i have a value "g", then i should get the name as col3 ` in which condition you shoul get `col3`.Please be more specific and `Edit`your question with `Expected Output`

Comment: @DevalShah i asked if i have value as g then i should get col1 not col3, as the value "g" is present in col1

Comment: Is it possible for you to use any scripting language? Coz, that'll to the job easily

Comment: @draxxxeus , m using it with php and also this task can be done with query itself

Comment: Why not to ask a question in a less cryptic way, using *real* field names and values, letting people whom you ask to help, more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @q= CONCAT('SELECT columns.column_name 
                from table inner 
                join information_schema.columns 
                on columns.table_schema = "dbname" 
                and columns.table_name = "table" 
                and ((',
                (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('columns.column_name="',column_name,'"',' and table.',column_name,' = "value','"') SEPARATOR ' OR ')
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                WHERE table_name = 'table'),
                '))');
prepare query from @q;
execute query;
```

This works for sure..

Phew!

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9420c/2/2

PS: Replace `table` with your table name ,`dbname` with your db name and `value` with your value

Comment: In the first statement?? Check the statement after you have substituted the value

Answer (score -1):

As you encrypted your question as much as possible, I can only guess.

this table smells of a bad design. And it should be like

```
 col  | value
 col1 | a
 col1 | b
 col2 | d
```

and so on.

than you can easily get your col out from value

Comment: Exactly, that is the table design...for his problem.

Comment: do i really need to change my table design , now my table is pretty simple , i just need to get the column name thats it