# SQLITE query to retrieve the column name based on value of column

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Hello I have looked on these forums and I need help with getting name of column based on value.

For example I have a table such as:

```
|Name  | Column1 | Column2 | Column3|
|-----------------------------------|
|Peter | 100     | 120     | 92     |
|-----------------------------------|
|James | 110     | 105     | 88     |
|-----------------------------------|
|David | 90      | 112     | 98     |
```

I want to do a query of Peter where the value is 92 and I need the query to return Column3.

I know very basic sql and have not really used sqlite to understand it in depth.

I searched and the best I found was this thread which does have a solution that works on mysql: [Get column name dynamically by Specific row value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621714/get-column-name-dynamically-by-specific-row-value).

I tested this and it does exactly what I would like.
Of course it's not for sqlite.

I need to know if this can be done using sqlite and if so, what is the proper syntax?
Again I know very basic SQL.

If anyone has any tips/advice I appreciate it.

Comment: How many columns in the table?

Comment: What programming language are you using to access SQLite? SQLite has a built-in method to retrieve the column name from a result set column, since it keeps track of the source column at least with simple SELECT and JOIN queries.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am developing in C# and using the ADO.NET 2.0 Provider for SQLite(http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/), which I had downloaded a long time ago.  If there are better options than the one I am using I'm all ears, but so far it works fine.  I guess I'll have to look up this built-in method you mentioned, I was just curious if anyone knew a good method of doing this.  Worst case I can retrieve the full result and do in-app coding to do what I want, but would rather do it on SQL end.

Comment: Checkout the `ColumnName` method in the source code you linked. It's present in the SQLite3.cs file. It takes a `SQLiteStatement` and the index of the column whose name you want.

Answer (score 1):

if the columns are few and names fixed you could use this :-

```
select case when col1 == 92 then col1 
            when col2 == 92 then col2 
            when col3 == 92 then col3
       end
  from tab;
```

Comment: There are 18 columns so it may be a little ugly, although it would be an options still. Thanks.

Comment: In that case and perhaps even otherwise @Anurag has suggested the right approach for this.

Comment: I tried the sql statement posted above and get error, is the syntax correct for sqlite3?

Comment: added end marker for case stmt and removed quotes around colnames