# MySQL and get column headers where cell equals value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table with many columns (40+).  The first column is an ID column and the rest are columns which only take values of 0 or 1.  Is there a query in which i can search the row and see which "cells" are equal to 1 and return the column name?

For example, say my ID is 5 and columns 4,9,23 each have a 1 for that row (all others are zero).  Therefore i would want to return "Column4","Column9" and "Column23" as my result.  I need the ID stipulation in there too so I know which row to examine.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Will you explain what you are trying to accomplish with this type of table structure? There may be a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: This is more of a question of being able to find a way to accomplish the goal with the given table structure.  It seems like something close to `SELECT * FROM table.columns WHERE id=5 AND table.*.value = 1` would work.  I'm just not quite sure on the appropriate terminology.

Comment: I was trying to build up an answer based on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16622414/2589202).  But sqlfiddle doesnt support it.  Perhaps you can modify it to work for you.

Comment: Do you want to return just one row for you example, or should it be a row per column?