# Dropping a column in sql table based on its value not column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table with its column_names are created dynamically and values come from XML but some columns have NULL value and I would like to drop them from the table.
the command:

```
ALTER TABLE ##temptable
DROP COLUMN COLUMN_NAME
```

works perfect if I knew the column_name but since column_names are created dynamically, I would not know them. example:

```
animal | human | things | stars  | cars
5      | name  | null   | bright | null
```

so the columns 'things' and 'cars' that created dynamically needed to be dropped, so it would look like this:

```
 animal | human | stars
    5   | name  | bright
```

is there way to do that (I don't want to create view)?

Comment: You are only ever going to have 1 row in the table?  What happens when you have more than one row?

Comment: Huh? You want to drop a column based on the value in the column? This is like buying a house based on the car parked in the driveway.

Comment: yes, 1 row in the table.  yes, dropping the column based on its null value.

Comment: can you post a sample XML? It may be easier to build `DROP COLUMN` statement straight from the XML data.

Comment: That would be a very long discussion and change of program architecture. But if I could drop the null columns it would solve a lot of problems. I thought someone has already figured this out to drop a column based on its null value???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following. Of course, you should be adding more validation to be sure it doesn't fail.

```
create table #tmp (user_id int, col1 int, col2 int)

declare @column_to_drop nvarchar(100) = 'col1'
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'ALTER TABLE #tmp DROP COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(@column_to_drop)

exec sp_executesql @sql

select * from #tmp
```

Good luck.

LATER EDIT:

You can try this. The only thing needed to know is temp table name.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (a nvarchar(max), b nvarchar(10), c nvarchar(100), d nvarchar(1000), e datetime, f int)
INSERT #tmp VALUES ('1', null, '2', null, GETDATE(), null)

SELECT  * 
FROM    #tmp

SELECT  name, CAST(0 AS BIT) checked
INTO    #col_names
FROM    tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp')

DELETE C
FROM    (   SELECT *
            FROM #tmp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS T(XMLCol)
        CROSS APPLY T.XMLCol.nodes('*') AS n(Col) 
        INNER JOIN #col_names C
            ON c.name = Col.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)')

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ', ' + QUOTENAME(name), QUOTENAME(name))
FROM    #col_names

SET     @sql = 'ALTER TABLE #tmp DROP COLUMN ' + @sql

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)

SELECT  * 
FROM    #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp
DROP TABLE #col_names
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but your suggested solution assumes that I know the column name i.e. 'col1' but i don't know (wrong assumption). I only know the value for the column is NULL but nothing about its name. the table has only one row and some of the columns' value can be NULL.

Comment: I`ve updated the answer above, it should be ok for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much but when I tested your suggested solution, it only worked with your INT data type. When I changed the data type to varchar or nvarchar your script failed to drop the columns. I also tested the script against my auto generated table with the data type as you guessed correctly is in varchar for all columns which did not work. I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631822/to-get-column-names-from-table-having-a-particular-value which gives me the column name for NULL values and now trying to use it to write a script to drop columns or accept if anyone has it

Comment: updated reply! Thank you very much but when I tested your suggested solution, it only worked with your INT data type. It worked for varchar datatype, but when had 'NULL' as inserted value rather than NULL the script failed. so I am going to test again. However, Found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631822/to-get-column-names-from-table-having-a-particular-value which gives me the column name for NULL values and now trying to use it to write a script to drop columns or accept if anyone has it

Comment: I tried your script against my table with sql = 'NULL' and sql = NULL, both cases failed to drop the columns. I am not sure why??

Comment: I went through the code and understand it now. thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Horia, I have to change all the datatype to nvarchar(50) to get your script to work although I don't know the column names but the datatype are known and can vary from nvarchar(10) to nvarchar(max). I believe unpivot function causes the issue, do you have any suggestion on how to solve this issue? thanks.

Comment: Hi, I`ve tested the script before hand on various datatypes, but all the same - maybe i wasn't clear enough, but also sizes if you use nvarchar must match. if you dont like that, there's also a way with a while to loop through columns and check if their value is null and drop it if yes. Let me know if you still need help with this.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could provide me with the while loop solution too. I spent 2 days on this and still some parts don't work as it should.

Comment: Ok, i`ve updated my answer to take whatever type you have and drop if null. Have look.