# SELECT id and COLUMN_NAME of where entry 'x' was found

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say spreadsheet below represents my database table.

[image: database table]

I need a query that searches this table on entry '1000' and gives me the 'id' and its column_name where it was found. I will end up with the following result set:

```
id   column_name
---  ---------
1    column_c
2    column_a
2    column_d
4    column_d
```

I know this is quite a unusual question about database querying, because I haven't really found what I am looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631822/to-get-column-names-from-table-having-a-particular-value

Comment: @Vishu238 That q/a can't be a duplicate as it targets MS SQL Server and uses syntax and constructs that are not available in MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is to unpivot the table so that the columns becomes rows and then filter the rows with matching value. As MySQL doesn't have any `unpivot` operator we can do this using a bunch of queries joined as a set using `union`. Each query includes a literal value specifying the source column name.

```
select id, 'Column_a' Col from your_table where column_a = 1000 -- or like '1000%' etc.
union all
select id, 'Column_b' Col from your_table where column_b = 1000
union all
select id, 'Column_c' Col from your_table where column_c = 1000
union all
select id, 'Column_d' Col from your_table where column_d = 1000
order by id, Col
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fad1ec/1)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yeah that might be better, why not write it up as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski This is exactly what I'm looking for. Could you show me how the query would look like with the CASE?

Comment: @MarijnvanGool Actually, the CASE only works if there's exactly one matching 1000. Is that always true?

Comment: @jpw I was just realizing that as well.

Comment: The value actually contains something like '1000 - something', that would mean that I only have to replace ' = 1000' with LIKE '1000%'.

Comment: @MarijnvanGool Indeed.

Comment: @MarijnvanGool CASE would look something like: `select id, case when c1 = 1000 then "c1" when c2 = 1000 then "c2" when c3 = 1000 then "c3" when c4 = 1000 then "c4" end as the_col from test where c1 = 1000 or c2 = 1000 or c3 = 1000 or c4 = 1000;` - with the mentioned exact match problem.